# XML to XSL transform

Tags: css, xml, xslt, xsd

I'm a newbie at XSL / XML. I would like to make a simple XSL of the below XML code, that just shows the attributes name and adress? I have most of the XSL but I can't write the part where it shows my results (the customers).

This is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="customer.xsl"?>
<customers xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="customer.xsd">
    <customer name="Jay Z" address="New York, trinity st. 300, USA"/>
    <customer name="Vladimir Putin" address="St. Petersburg, wadim street 23, Russia"/>
    <customer name="Hiro Nakamura" address="Kyoto, Natsukawa street 49, Japan"/>
</customers>
```

Like this?

```
<xsl:value-of select="customers/customer"/>
```

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, not very good with english!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XSL itself would look like the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="customers/customer">
   <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="@address"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

[This code as working example](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/LnwyBT/2)

For a more detailed example look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex3)